# Java / Android Studio / If statement not being executed despite it matching the condition

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I have been coding for decades and have used many different languages. Currently I am doing a simple Java app for a Uni course. The coursework is easy but I have run into a problem with an if statement that simply doesn't wish to execute even when it matches the condition.

I'm going to admit that I'm a little embarrassed to ask such a simple question but it's a problem that I have spent more time that I care admit trying to resolve.

Allow me to elaborate:

I have two variables, one private local and one generated, both are defined as *int*. **_selectedImage** and **clickedImageID**, both are provided to a *public void* function that checks if they are the same. The first time the app is run they will be the same, every other time the function is run it is not.

However no matter what I do, it simply doesn't want to execute the if block. Let me demonstrate:

```
private int _selectedImage;

public void setPuzzlePiece(int clickedImageID) {
 // selectedImage == clickedImageID on first run.
 Boolean firstRun = (clickedImageID == _selectedImage);
 if (firstRun==false) {
  // do stuff
  String debugPoint = "adding this here just to attach a debug point";
 }
}
```

I have provided a screenshot from the debug process that highlights the values:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN7Xq.png

You will see the relevant values of *4* and *5*, both *int*, for *clickedImageID* and *_selectedImage*, while *firstRun* is **false**.

Spot how despite the condition being met the debugger thinks that there is no executable code found at line 77, and stepping through the debugger it just "ignores" the if condition. Yet we can all see the logic, it's quite clear that it should execute the block.

I initially had this as a simple comparison. `if (_selectedImage==clickedImageID) { .. }` But have shifted the condition to a boolean and compared on that. I have also tried numerous ways of detecting for false such as `(firstRun==false)`, `(!firstRun)` and `(firstRun==(!true))` amongst many other silly ways, but it's as simple as simple can be, just comparing a boolean with either true or false should be enough.

If I use the evaluation window it returns what the screenshot shows, that the if block condition is met but it still won't execute it.

This could be something to do with Java and it's comparisons. As I use multiple languages I can sometimes get caught out with the foibles of each one; for instance in c# you can compare strings via ==, while in Java you use equals().

It HAS to be something I am doing wrong, but for the life of me I cannot see it. Help me spot my stupidity SO!

- ps: I checked to see if this was a duplicate question and while a few threads relate to similar, they are in PHP or C++, not Java, and of the Java one it's a simple syntax error that failed them. This is, from what I can see, not the issue here. *

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a lower case "boolean" as type for your firstRun

Comment: Since the code at line 77 doesn't do anything, it has likely been optimized away, which is why "there is no executable code found" there. The underlining of `debugPoint` is likely a warning saying something like that. Try changing it to a print or log statement.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I will do, that might be the issue, as I say it's each language's foibles that catch me out, I take it Boolean != boolean (and I mean that in general, they are obviously different objects).

Comment: @Andreas yeah, I appreciate that, my issue is that it shouldn't. The if block should be executed based on the variables within the scope of that function.

Comment: Actually they would be the same object, but it's still better to write the condition as `if (! firstRun)`. --- Notice the space after `!` to help make the operator more visible. It might otherwise be missed when visually quick-scanning the source code.

Comment: *"it shouldn't"*? Have you disabled all optimizers to make sure that doesn't happen?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing - even changing from Boolean to boolean doesn't resolve it. :(

Comment: But does changing to a print statement solve it?

Comment: @Andreas  Why would I want to change it to a print, what benefit? The evaluation window shows all the variables are within scope and firstRun is set to false, yet the if (!firstRun) simply doesn't work in the code. I will admit I'm pretty bloody confused here.

Comment: *"what benefit?"* To prevent optimizer from throwing the code away. --- *"The evaluation window shows all the variables"* So why isn't it showing the value of `debugPoint`? --- Both `if (firstRun==false)` and `if (! firstRun)` works correctly, you just can't see that, because there is no code inside the block, as visually shown with the stop sign.

Comment: @Andreas Ok, sorry I misread that, I thought you wished me to start printing out the debug data. I have amended the simple string variable with a System.out.print, it still remains the same problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am going to be honest here I really don't understand what is going on, I have rewritten my function (keeping the same name and arguments) to this..

```
    public void setPuzzlePiece(int clickedImageID) {
            boolean areEqual = (clickedImageID == _selectedImage);
            if (!areEqual) {
                System.out.print("they are equal");
            }
    }
```

..and yet lo and behold, it now executes the if block when `!areEqual`. If anyone is willing to point out why this code above works and the code I posted in my OP doesn't then I would be heartily grateful as I would love not to run into this problem again.

I should point out I did nothing other than in the IDE, delete the function contents (retaining the definition) and replaced firstRun with areEqual.

Is **firstRun** somehow native to the Android system? You'd expect the compiler to raise the issue, but that seems (to me) to be the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share some more details about the question or else paste entire code over here in the question section.

I have used nearly the same code and it works fine for me.

```
class Test{
    private static int _selectedImage;

    public static void setPuzzlePiece(int clickedImageID) {
        Boolean firstRun = (clickedImageID == _selectedImage);
        if (firstRun == false) {
            String debugPoint = "adding this here just to attach a debug point";
            System.out.println(debugPoint);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        _selectedImage = 10;
        setPuzzlePiece(11);
    }
}
```

Output - **adding this here just to attach a debug point**

Try rebooting you IDE or invalidate cache.

Comment: https://ideone.com/sfvgnn you can compile and run the code here.

Comment: I'm going to be honest here, I'd need to share the whole project and I'm a bit loathe to do that to be honest as it's half finished. There are no compiler errors, mind, and the debugger shows the correct flow and variables. 

I tried using ideone but it threw out a lot of compiler errors, none of which are present when I compile the app and run it via the android emulator. The app runs and operates exactly as intended in Android Studio, barring this conditional if block, so I'm guessing ideone is not designed for Android stuff.

Comment: Could you try to re-start you IDE or invalidate the cache.

Comment: I have restarted the IDE (and emulator) numerous times, and with clearing the cache are you meaning on the AVD image cache or is there cache elsewhere.

I apologise for my inexperience with Android Studio, I've only been using it for a few weeks and still find it "annoying".

Comment: No prob, in most of the IDE's you have option to invalidate the cache of IDE. I am not sure about the tool you are using have that feature or not. It is there in IntelliJ Idea , Eclipse ...

Comment: Android Studio is essentially Idea: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq ..both produced by IntelliJ. The only reason I don't use Idea is because the current version has a huge bug that stops me editing attribute fields. There are several bug trackers both at IntelliJ and Google confirming this issue and there is no resolution for it.

Answer (score 0):

It works on my machine... When i run this code it reaches the print statement.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    setPuzzlePiece(3);

}

private static int _selectedImage = 1;

public static void setPuzzlePiece(int clickedImageID) {
    // selectedImage == clickedImageID on first run.
    Boolean firstRun = (clickedImageID == _selectedImage);
    if (firstRun == false) {
        // do stuff
        System.out.println("adding this here just to attach a debug point");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that and yeah, this is the problem, it should work, the code I've presented should work, the debug data shows it should work, yet it doesn't. It's clear that it's something **I** am doing but for the life of me I can't see it.

Comment: So is this code working as expected? Then it looks like your picture isn't correct. Maybe reboot or invalidate cashes.

Comment: your code is the same as mine, except a system.out to rather than a string assignment. Essentially what happens inside the if block is sort of irrelevant if that block refuses to execute.

Although I appreciate the effort made.

Comment: @user3311217 That's the point. Since the code is the same there should be something other wrong that has nothing to do with the code. And if you check that  there is no difference between your code and code that actually uses a variable instead of just declaring it(what could be optimized out) you would know for sure

Comment: As I say, I've been coding for decades, I've gone through all the usual things that would trip this up, scoping, spelling, assignments, casting, etc...

There is something wrong, that we can agree on. I presume firstRun isn't a reserved word in Java - even if it was the local scoping is the one used in the condition. Plus if I was using reserved words I'd expect that to be flagged up by the IDE or the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the value of firstRun using firstRun.toString(); outside if statement.
and also the values of clickedImageID and _selectedImage using toString() method.

Comment: As fristRun is a boolean, there is no toString() method available to it, same for the two int's,